# ArcGIS 10.2 Undo after operationbase esri.dijit.editing.Union operation throws undefined or null reference error

Tags: javascript, union, polygon, arcgis

I am trying to implement a polygon union operation using ArcGIS 10.2 JavaScript 3.6 API with undo, redo capabilities. I am able to perform the union operation, but when I try to undo the operation I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at line 19, column 1879 in http://js.arcgis.com/3.6/js/esri/dijit/editing/Cut.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Code Snippet:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("Merge_Button"), "onClick", function () {
    editing_function = "Merge_From";
    document.getElementById("Status_Message").innerHTML = "Select Polygon to Merge From"
    esri.bundle.toolbars.draw.addPoint = "Select Polygon to Merge From";
    drawToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);
});

dojo.connect(drawToolbar, "onDrawEnd", function (geometry) {

if (editing_function == "Merge_From") {
    var point_selectQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();
    point_selectQuery.geometry = geometry;

    edit_featurelayer.selectFeatures(point_selectQuery, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {
        if (features.length == 0) {
            r = confirm("Nothing Selected. Try again?");
            if (r == true) {
                return;
            }
            drawToolbar.deactivate();
            document.getElementById("Status_Message").innerHTML = "Nothing exciting going on around here";
            return
        }
        merge_from_features = features;
        editing_function = "Merge_To";
        document.getElementById("Status_Message").innerHTML = "Select Polygon to Merge To";
        esri.bundle.toolbars.draw.addPoint = "Select Polygon to Merge To";
    });
    return;
}

if (editing_function == "Merge_To") {
    var point_selectQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();
    point_selectQuery.geometry = geometry;
    edit_featurelayer.selectFeatures(point_selectQuery, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_ADD, function (features) {
        if (features.length == 0) {
            r = confirm("Nothing Selected. Try again?");
            if (r == true) {
                return;
            }
            drawToolbar.deactivate();
            document.getElementById("Status_Message").innerHTML = "Nothing exciting going on around here";
            return
        }
        merge_to_features = features;
        editing_function = "";
        document.getElementById("Status_Message").innerHTML = "Nothing exciting going on around here";
        drawToolbar.deactivate();

        var input_geometries;
        try {

            var from_g = merge_from_features[0].geometry;
            var to_g = merge_to_features[0].geometry;
            var input_geometries = [from_g, to_g];

            geometryService.union(input_geometries, function (unioned_geometry) {
                var merge_from_feature = merge_from_features[0];
                var merge_to_feature = merge_to_features[0];

                var original_feature = merge_to_feature.toJson();
                merge_to_feature.geometry = unioned_geometry;

                edit_featurelayer.applyEdits(null, [merge_to_feature], [merge_from_feature], function () {
                    try {

                        var operation = new esri.dijit.editing.Union({
                            deleted_graphics: [merge_from_feature],
                            featureLayer: edit_featurelayer,
                            preUpdatedGraphics: new esri.Graphic(original_feature),
                            postUpdatedGraphics: [merge_to_feature]
                        });

                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert(err.message);
                    };
                    undoManager.add(operation);
                    checkUI();
                });
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.message);
        };
    });


    return;
};

drawToolbar.deactivate();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I had to change the following code from:

```
                    var operation = new esri.dijit.editing.Union({
                        deleted_graphics: [merge_from_feature],
                        featureLayer: edit_featurelayer,
                        preUpdatedGraphics: new esri.Graphic(original_feature),
                        postUpdatedGraphics: [merge_to_feature]
                    });
```

to:

```
                    var operation = new esri.dijit.editing.Union({
                        deletedGraphics: [merge_from_feature],
                        featureLayer: edit_featurelayer,
                        postUpdatedGraphics: new esri.Graphic(original_feature),
                        preUpdatedGraphics: [merge_to_feature]
                    });
```